# Get inlier points not rejected by correspondence distance in pcl registration methods.

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am using the `pcl` implementation of `iterative closest point`. I would like to be able to play with the inlier points from any registration method that I use.

The `registration` class has the ability to output an aligned cloud when the align function is called:

```
icp_.align(outcloud, guess);
```

And the `PCLBase` class has the following function:

```
indices = icp_.getIndices();
```

Unfortunately `getIndices` just returns the indices for the entire cloud. I have tested on a cloud and **the outliers (or inliers) rejected by distance correspondence don't seem to be retrievable?**

I have checked and there are points in the cloud that should have been rejected, see below:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off of D.J.Duff's answer, here's one way to get at corresponding points, though it involves violating the class. This one inherits from the IterativeClosestPointNonLinear class and can act as a substitute. For my use case, I just dropped it in wherever I wanted to use IterativeClosestPointNonLinear and be able to access the `correspondences_` member. A similar approach could be used for any of the other registration interfaces.

```
/** \brief This is a mock class with the sole purpose of accessing a protected member of a class it inherits from.
*
* Some of the relevant documentation for correspondences: http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/correspondence_8h_source.html#l00092
*/
template <typename PointSource, typename PointTarget, typename Scalar = float>
class IterativeClosestPointNonLinear_Exposed : public pcl::IterativeClosestPointNonLinear<PointSource, PointTarget, Scalar> {
  public:
    pcl::CorrespondencesPtr getCorrespondencesPtr() {
      for (uint32_t i = 0; i < this->correspondences_->size(); i++) {
        pcl::Correspondence currentCorrespondence = (*this->correspondences_)[i];
        std::cout << "Index of the source point: " << currentCorrespondence.index_query << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Index of the matching target point: " << currentCorrespondence.index_match << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Distance between the corresponding points: " << currentCorrespondence.distance << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Weight of the confidence in the correspondence: " << currentCorrespondence.weight << std::endl;
      }
      return this->correspondences_;
    }
};
```

Here are some lines drawn between corresponding points between two point clouds obtained in this manner. Notably, the `pcl::Correspondence.distance` value between two points doesn't always seem to be strictly less than the value of the registration method's `maxCorrespondenceDistance`, so you may have to check the distances to make sure you're getting only the correspondences you want.

[image: Point correspondences between two clouds.]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may get you want with the protected `correspondences_` member:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_registration.html#a98f1c160391fff07f34339b63286e228

As it is protected you probably should subclass ICP and add an accessor method.

For more information about how this member is used, see:

http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/icp_8hpp_source.html

Comment: NOTE: the ICP code changes between PCL versions so look at the code for your version.

Comment: Surely there is a better way then violating the class. I would also have to implement my own function for retrieving the points. Not that that is a problem but I thought pcl would have thought of that? Thanks for this, I will start implementing, I wouldn't have thought of inheriting from icp to steal its protected members.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a violation. An alternative would be to put an appropriate accessor method directly into the class. I'm sure upstream wouldn't mind you sending a patch too if the change is thought through.